# Center content area around font?

Tags: html, css, fonts

I have noticed that the content area around my font is not centered. This is causing issues because I want to apply a background to the header but it looks really ugly when not centered. Without placing another div wrapper around it, is there any better solution that can fix this problem? Also, does anyone know why this problem occurs for some fonts?

Here is my CSS code for good measure.

```
header h1 { 
    font-family: komika_axisregular;
    font-size: 10em;
    color: #f7f7f8;
    margin: 100px 0 50px 0;
    line-height: 0.7em;
    background-color: rgba(46, 52, 54, 0.5);
}
```

Here is an example of the problem font, and then an example of a good font. Both are using the exact same CSS code.
[image: Problem font]
[image: Good Font]

Comment: In first image we can see the font-size bigger than line-height ? Is this it ? And .. what is the second font-family ??

Comment: The line-height is not the issue. I can make the line-height much larger than the font, but it is still off-centered. The second font is bebas neue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

None of the people's responses really helped for my situation. The main reason why I went through so much trouble with doing this was because I wanted to have full control of the width and height of the semi-transparent background. I did not want the background to be the width of the title for aesthetic reasons. Here was my final result:

**HTML**

```
<body>
    <h1>
        <div id="bg-wrap">
            <div id="name-bg"></div> 
        </div>
        <a href="index.html">BRADLEY TSE</a>
     </h1>
</body>
```

**CSS**

h1 style

```
header h1 {
    font-family: bebas_neueregular;
    font-size: 16em;
    color: #ffb477;
    margin: 110px 0 40px 0;
}
```

Since the a element came after, I needed to change the z-index to make it appear on top of the background. This is probably not the proper way to do this, but I didn't want to mess around with the positioning of the elements anymore right now.

```
h1 a {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1000;
}
```

This was used to properly position the #name-bg element in the center of the screen.

```
#bg-wrap {
    position: absolute; 
    right:50%;
}
```

Overlaid a semi-transparent background on top of my name.

```
#name-bg {
    position: relative;
    right: -50%;
    height: 110px;
    width: 620px;
    margin-top: 24px;
    background-color: rgba(46, 52, 54, 0.8);
    z-index: 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Place a `<span>` tag around the font and try background coloring that, this might look different in different browsers, you always should structure your html standard so this things dont happen, its because of differences in font rendering and even format of font used to embed to your page.

Comment: I am going to try this and let you know how it goes.